# Could not resolve host local sites inside homestead

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

The issue is I can't ping or curl any sites inside homestead, below is my homestead.yaml but when I tried to run in homestead terminal

`curl -GET http://modules-api.local` I am getting an error below

`could not resolve host: modules-api.local`

but when trying to curl/ping external websites like 
`curl -GET http://facebook.com` I am getting the expected response, the error only occurs when trying to curl sites inside homestead

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 4096
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
mongodb: true

authorize: /Users/Edgar/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /Users/Edgar/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: F:/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:

    - map: modules-api.local
      to: /home/vagrant/code/modules-api/public  

    - map: auth.local
      to: /home/vagrant/code/authserver/public


databases:
    - homestead
```

Comment: Did you add the hostname to your hosts file (eg. `192.168.10.10  modules.api.local`)?

Comment: You're not going to resolve your Vagrant's host unless you 1) use an IP address (e.g. 192.168.10.10), 2) Configure DHCP, and your LAN's DHCP server has dynamic DNS (as most home and lab routers do), and/or 3) add the address to /etc/hosts.  Look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead#accessing-homestead-globally) for more details, but this is a "TCP/IP 101" issue; *not* a Vagrant problem, not a Homestead problem.

Comment: @l'L'l yes I did and it is working as intended, my only problem was when using curl to access project 2 from project 1

Comment: @eaponz, looks like we had the same issue with the same solution but I don't find it solid. Did you find out why this was happening? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57157729/laravel-homestead-cant-ping-from-inside-of-the-vm-any-local-sites

Answer (score 1):

I got it working

after running `vagrant ssh` go to `sudo nano /etc/hosts`

then add the list of projects you want to be accessible in homestead

ex.
127.0.1.1    modules-api.local